# I cannot install PyQt on my PyCharm, it says I need Windows Build Tools but I HAVE that. Reinstalled pip, and VS as per google

Tags: python, visual-studio, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt5

> c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'bool.cpp': No such
>   file or directory
>
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
>   failed with exit status 2
>
> ---
>
> Failed building wheel for PyQt5-sip
>
> Running setup.py clean for PyQt5-sip
>
> Failed to build PyQt5-sip
>
> Could not build wheels for PyQt5-sip which use PEP 517 and cannot be
>   installed directly

Comment: Which version of pip are you using?

Comment: I'm running 20.0.2 I just checked on the cmd

Comment: pip 20.0.2 shouldn't give you that error. How are you installing PyQt5? From the settings menu in PyCharm?

Comment: I installed it using the cmd, that didn't work, I tried it through PyQt5, same error, and then I tried through the PyCharm terminal, it gave me the same error. Edit* I'm running pip 19.0.3 when I check in PyCharm but 20.0.2 from cmd

Comment: You could try running `python -m pip install -U pip` from the cmd in PyCharm to update pip in PyCharm (this will probably give a bunch of errors but will update pip anyway) and then run `python -m pip install PyQt5`. Or you could go to File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter, click on + sign on right-hand side of the table, and install pip first and then PyQt5.